# 400 Bad Request when accessing service after publishing app to IIS

Tags: angular, wcf, iis, .net-core

I have an Angular app created in dot net core which accesses a SOAP service on port 80 that runs on a different server, but I publish the angular app to the same server but on a different port as the SOAP service I get a 400 Bad Request. The app works locally when accessing the SOAP service the error only happens after publishing the app. Any advise?

the error:

POST http://localhost:80/api/Security/DownloadRemitance 400 (Bad Request)

message: "Http failure response for http://localhost:80/api/Security/DownloadRemitance: 400 Bad Request"

Comment: You post to port 90 and not 80 as you mentioned

Comment: Hi there, thanks for the feedback, I accidentally miss typed I meant to say it runs on port 80. So the application runs on port 90 and the service which it accesses runs on port 80 as corrected in above question.